# PHP: why my sessions always dont work on server?

Tags: php, session

I have problem that my sessions works correctly on localhost, but it always creates problem when I upload it on server. Interesting thing is that it has problem with every server on which I have uploaded yet. Is there any problem on my localhost.

**Problem:**The problem which I faced this time is that sessions are set on local pages, means that when I set sessions by login it sets on login page but remain unset on other pages

#### Here is code of login page

```
<?php
    session_start();
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Belvic Print - Register</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Printing template">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=3.0, user-scalable=yes"/>
        <meta name="author" content="Netbase">
        <!--Add css lib-->  
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style-main.css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500,300,700,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--Header: Begin-->
        <header>
            <!--Top Header: Begin-->a-home"></i>
                                        <span>Thessaly House, Thessaly Road, London, SW8 4EB</span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                                        <span>0203 868 3785</span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                                        <span><a href="mailto:support@netbaseteam.net" title="send mail to Cmsmart">support@netbaseteam.net</a></sp</li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" title="FAQ">FAQ</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" title="Design Service">Design Services</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 other-info footer-col hidden-sm">
                            <h2>Other Info</h2>
                            <div class="footer-content">
                                <p>
                                    Printmart provides fast online printing for both homes and businesses. We  provide high quality business cards, postcards, flyers, brochures, stationery and  other premium online print products.
                                </p>
                                <img src="images/footer-payment.png" alt="Payment method">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-bottom">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <p class="copy-right">Central - Copyright © 2015 <a title="Cmsmart - Magento theme" href="#">netbaseteam.com</a>. All Rights Reserved</p>
                            <a href="#" id="back-to-top">
                                <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
                                Top
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
        <div id="sitebodyoverlay"></div>
        <nav id="mb-main-menu" class="main-menu">
            <div class="mb-menu-title">
                <h3>Navigation</h3>
                <span id="close-mb-menu">
                    <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
                </span>
            </div>
            <ul  class="cate_list">
                <li class="level0 parent col1 all-product">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span>All Product</span>
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="level0">
                        <li class="level1">
                            <a href="#" title="Business Card">Business Card</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="level1">
                            <a href="#" title="Premium Business Card">Premium Business Card</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="level1">
                            <a href="#" title="Free Business Card">Free Business Card</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="level1">
                            <a href="#" title="Marketing Materials">Marketing Materials</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="level1">
                            <a href="#" title="Dance Marketing Kit">Dance Marketing Kit</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="level1 view-all-pro">
                            <a href="#" title="view all product">View all</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="level0 parent col1">
                    <a href="#" title="Business Cards">
                        <span>Business Cards</span>
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="level0">
                        <li class="level1 nav-1-1 first item">
                            <a href="#" title="Premium Business Cards">Premium Business Cards</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="level1 nav-1-2 item">
                            <a href="#" title="Free Business Cards">Free Business Cards</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="level1 nav-1-3 item">
                            <a href="#" title="Die-Cut Business Cards">Die-Cut Business Cards</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="level1 nav-1-4 item">
                            <a href="#" title="Standard Business Cards">Standard Business Cards</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="level1 nav-1-5 item">
                            <a href="#" class="Personal Business Cards">Personal Business Cards</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="level1 nav-1-6 item">
                            <a href="#" title="Business Card Holders">Business Card Holders</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="level1 nav-1-7 item">
                            <a href="#" title="Networking Cards">Networking Cards</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="level1 nav-1-8 item">
                            <a href="#" title="Appointment Cards">Appointment Cards</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="level1 nav-1-9 last item">
                            <a href="#" title="Mommy Cards">Mommy Cards</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="level0">
                    <a href="#" title="Marketing">Marketing</a>
                </li>
                <li class="level0">
                    <a href="#" title="Postcards">Postcards</a>
                </li>
                <li class="level0">
                    <a href="#" title="Stickers & Badges">Stickers & Badges</a>
                </li>
                <li class="level0" title="Promotional">
                    <a href="#">Promotional</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <!--Add js lib-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.animateSlider.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/theme.js"></script>
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    include("db.php");
    if(isset($_POST['register'])) {
    // , , , ,
        $fname = $_POST['fname'];
        $lname = $_POST['lname'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $confirmpassword = $_POST['confirmpassword'];
        $_username = $_POST['username'];
        $status = "new";
        $rank="user";

        if($password==$confirmpassword)
        {
            $checkforregister = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$email'";
            if($result=mysqli_query($conn,$checkforregister)) {
                if (mysqli_num_rows($result) != 1) {
                        $insert = "INSERT INTO user (first_name, last_name, email, password, username,status,rank) VALUES
    ('$fname','$lname','$email','$password','$_username','$status','$rank')";
                    if(mysqli_query($conn,$insert)) {
                        $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

                        $_SESSION['id'] = $last_id;
                        $userRecord = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id='$last_id'");

                        while ($recordLoop = mysqli_fetch_array($userRecord)) {

                            $_SESSION['rank'] = $recordLoop['rank'];
                        }
                        ?>
                        <script>
                            window.location="index.php";
                        </script>
                        <?php
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo mysqli_error($conn);
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<div class='span6' style='margin-top: -7%'><p style='color: red;bottom: 50%'>Your email already exists</p></div>";
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {

             echo "<div class='span6' style='margin-top: -7%'><p style='color: red;bottom: 50%'>Your password doesn't match</p></div>";
        }

    }
    if(isset($_POST['login']))
    {
        $emailLogin = $_POST['emailLogin'];
        $passwordLogin =  $_POST['passwordLogin'];
        $login_query="SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$emailLogin' AND password='$passwordLogin'";
        $run=mysqli_query($conn,$login_query) or die($conn);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($run)>0) {
            $res = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$emailLogin'");

            while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
                $_SESSION['id'] = $record['id'];
                $_SESSION['rank'] = $record['rank'];
            }
            echo $_SESSION['id'];
            ?>
            <script>
                window.location="index.php";
            </script>

    <?php
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<div class='span6' style='margin-top: -7%'><p style='color: red;bottom: 50%'>Your email or pssword is incorrect</p></div>";
        }
    }


    ?>
```

Comment: basic debugging: check `session_id()` on every page. if it changes, then you're losing the session cookie and getting a new/different session each time.

Comment: ^ *Yeah, that's the ticket!*

Comment: What is the solution for this?

Comment: @Marc B. I have checked. It changes

Comment: did you tried `session` simply that it works?

Comment: Sessions are working on my localhost. But when I upload it on server it always creates problem

Comment: Have you checked the `session_save_path()`, whether it exists and writable?

Comment: I have checked. It shows `/tmp`